# ModuleNotFoundError using pip

Tags: python, module

I have installed the module alpha_vantage using pip. In CMD writing import alpha_vantage does not show an error message, so I assume it is installed properly.

However, when trying to import alpha_vantage in a python program I get this error: `"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'". I assume the issue is due to the location of the module.`

The project is located here:
`C:\Users\M\Documents\Python\Investering`.

I tried placing the module here by pip: `C:\Users\M\Documents\Python\Investering\modules\alpha_vantage`

Note pip did not install the module there I simply copied the module folder and placed them in the project folder.

Is it possible to simply copy and paste module folders in other projects? Or how am I supposed to make python acknowledge the module?

The module was installed here:

`C:\Users\M\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\alpha_vantage`

I'm quite new to python. I have tried adding to `sys.path` the folder where the module was installed, but it did not seem to help. 
Thanks for any help.

Edit: I tried pip install requests and it produced this: 
`Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\martin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages`

Someone mentioned running: "pip install foo"
It, however, produces this error message:

`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement foo (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for foo`

I am using PyCharm.

Comment: Have you tried installing the missing module (ie `pip install requests`) ?

Comment: Run `pip install requests` and see what you get

Comment: As for the module management part, don't overcomplicate it, since pip is a package manager, it will... well, manage;) no need to copy folders or change $PATH, `pip install foo` and you should be able to use `import foo` straight away in Python, system-wide (or venv wide at least) !

Comment: I tried running pip install requests. It seemed in order. I got this: Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\m\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages

Comment: FYI, Python can only find modules in directories that are listed in the search path (`sys.path`). Just copying things around won't work. The pip program will install them in the right place (as long as it has file system permission).

Comment: Are you not using virtual environments or something similar? I would recommend doing so.

Answer (score 0):

I found my error. I had installed python from the website, but had unknowningly installed the 32 bit version, and a 64 bit version. I uninstalled all my python versions and pycharm. Then I reinstalled everything. Now I could easily make the module work. Thanks for the pointers.